# Facing issue of ClassLoader.loadLibrary() in open jdk 11.0.8+

Tags: java, java-11, pdftron

I have a project where I am using PDFNet jar for using its functionality. Recently I upgraded my openjdk version to **11.0.12** and started facing issue of NullPointerException while loading dll file.
Error Shown :

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  
        at pdftron.PDF.PDFNet.setTempPath(PDFNet.java:390)
        at abc.PdfViewerLicense.setupTempDirectory(PdfViewerLicense.java:70)
        at abc.PdfViewerLicense.<init>(PdfViewerLicense.java:44)
        at abc.PdfViewerLicense.initialize(PdfViewerLicense.java:98)
        at abc.PdfTronUtil.convertTextToPDF(PdfTronUtil.java:251)
        at abc.PdfTronUtilSpec.API to merge PDF file(PdfTronUtilSpec.groovy:167)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2649)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
        at com.pdftron.pdf.PDFNet.<clinit>(PDFNet.java:22)
```

Please suggest any solution for this issue in the given version of openjdk (11.0.12).

Tried with few openjdk versions above 11.0.8. Facing same issue in all version.

Comment: Does it work for versions below  11.0.8? Which version was the last known to work?

Comment: Please provide your code where you call `pdftron.PDF.PDFNet.setTempPath`. Though that is a very old version of PDFNet, the namespace for a long time now has been `com.pdftron.pdf.PDFNet.setTempPath()` so simply update the SDK might resolve your issue.

Comment: @Hulk : I tried with 11.0.7 . It was working in that version

Comment: @ryan : Here is sample code we are using 
public static void setTempPath(String var0) throws PDFNetException {
        try {
            com.pdftron.pdf.PDFNet.setTempPath(var0);
        } catch (com.pdftron.common.PDFNetException var2) {
            throw new PDFNetException(var2);
        }
    }

It is called using one method 
File tempPDFTron = new File ("my path")
if (! tempPDFTron.exists())
  {
   tempPDFTron.mkdirs();
  }
  PDFNet.setTempPath(tempPDFTron.toString());
  PDFNet.setPersistentCachePath(tempPDFTron.toString());

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow your comment. Please update your question to reflect that latest state you are in and the latest error/exception.